# How to pass command line arguments in kubernetes?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

Need to pass command line arguments for the docker containers appContainer1 & appContainer2 in the pod.yaml.

pod.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: microservices
  labels:
    app: apps
spec:
  containers:
    - name: appContainer1 
      image: gcr.io/mybucket/appContainerImage1 
      ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
    - name: appContainer2
      image: b.gcr.io/mybucket/appContainerImage2
      ports:
        - containerPort: 9090
```

In docker, I can pass the command line arguments via environment variable(-e)

```
docker run --rm -it -p 9090:9090 -e spring.profiles.dynamic=local applicationimage1
```

Similarly, I need to pass command line arguments when the containers run inside kubernetes.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It sounds like you don't actually want command line arguments, but environment variables - and you can use `env` for that:

```
- name: appContainer1 
  image: gcr.io/mybucket/appContainerImage1 
  ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
  env:
    - name: spring.profiles.dynamic
      value: local
```

You *can* use command line arguments:

```
- name: appContainer1 
  image: gcr.io/mybucket/appContainerImage1 
  ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
  args:
    - foo
    - bar
    - "String containing:colons:"
```

Comment: Sorry, env: key only support caps and it doesn't allow special charactes such as dot(.) and args is not working. please advise me.

Comment: @Shiva "is not working" is very vague. Please be more specific.

Comment: @Shiva: Likewise, what happens when you *try* the `env` as it is. (Is the limitation around capital letters documented? I didn't see it, but I may have missed it...)

Comment: @JonSkeet how can I pass flags ? example: `docker run --rm -it lapplicationimage1 -auth-file=somefile`

Comment: @user5980143: It's been a while since I've used docker, and I don't fancy looking up those flags right now, but you may just want to look at the Container documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.6/#container-v1-core