# Jenkins Docker image building for Different Tenant from same code repository

Tags: jenkins, configuration, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to implement CI/CD pipeline for my Spring Boot micro service deployment. I am planned to use Jenkins and Kubernetes for Making CI/CD pipeline. And I have one SVN code repository for version control.

**Nature Of Application**

Nature of my application is, one microservice need to deploy for multiple tenant. Actually code is same but database configuration is different for different tenant. And I am managing the configuration using Spring cloud config server.

**My Requirement**

My requirement is that, when I am committing code into my SVN code repository, then Jenkins need to pull my code, build project (Maven), And need to create Docker Image for multiple tenant. And need to deploy.

Here the thing is that, commit to one code repository need to build multiple docker image from same code repo. Means one code repo - multiple docker image building process. Actually, Dockerfile containing different config for different docker image ie. for different tenant. So here my requirement is that I need to build multiple docker images for different tenant with different configuration added in Dockerfile from one code repo by using Jenkins

**My Analysis**

I am currently planning to do this by adding multiple Jenkins pipeline job connect to same code repo. And within Jenkins pipeline job, I can add different configuration. Because Image name for different tenant need to keepdifferent and need to push image into Dockerhub.

**My Confusion**

Here my confusion is that,

1. Can I add multiple pipeline job from same code repository using Jenkins?
2. If I can add multiple pipeline job from same code repo, How I can deploy image for every tenant to kubernetes ? Do I need to add jobs for deployment? Or one single job is enough to deploy?

Comment: Pro tip: your questions are a bit chatty, and in my opinion (for what it is worth!) are not the kind of technical writing we ideally seek here. You have 70 questions containing a phrase of the form "Can anyone please help me to clarify my confusions about X please". The answer is invariably "yes" - not useful in itself - but it is also rather vague. If you have set out what you are specifically stuck on, then the chatty material can just be removed. Further reading: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/472495)

Comment: It's worth noting that language can affect how a question is received on Stack Overflow. Confident phraseology is generally received well, pleading and deference not so much. On that theme, this discussion may be of interest: [How can we encourage (new) authors to ask confident questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366264/472495)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be going about it a bit wrong.

Since your code is same for all the tenants and only difference is config, you should better create a single docker image and deploy it along with tenant specific configuration when deploying to Kubernetes.

So, your changes in your repository will trigger **one** Jenkins build and produce **one** docker image. Then you can have either multiple Jenkins jobs or multiple steps in pipeline which deploy the docker image with tenant specific config to Kubernetes.

If you don't want to heed to above, here are the answers to your questions:

1. You can create multiple pipelines from same repository in Jenkins. (Select `New item > pipeline` multiple times).
2. You can keep a list of tenants and just loop through OR run all deployments in parallel in a single pipeline stage.

Comment: Thank you for your response. There is one thing in your statement. I am not deploying with config. Instead of that I am building docker image with different configuration using spring cloud config server active profile functionality. I am adding dockerfile like following - FROM openjdk:8
ADD target/dockerDemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war dockerdemo.war
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "-Dspring.profiles.active=testprofile" , "dockerdemo.war"]

Comment: Here you can see that I am using spring cloud config server and active profile. If I am defining active profile ="Test" , then configuration with name "Test" will load from config server. Its containing one DB config. And I can set lot of profiles with different different DB config. And I only need to define which is active profile within Dockerfile. So the docker image will build with selected config. Then need to deploy. I am not doing like deploy with different config. When I am building Docker image , there itself I am building image with different config. It will load different DB confg

Comment: So I am looking for creating multiple pipeline job for same code repo. In each pipeline job I need to push the builded image into dockerhub according to the name that I am specifying. So when a commit is made to repo , 6 pipeline job need to trigger (Assume that I have 6 different tenant ). This is the way I am looking for. And your 2 points I am still exploring. I hope that you got my way of approach.

Comment: I would still say you have config `"-Dspring.profiles.active=testprofile"` which can be passed during deployment time.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34238765/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-in-kubernetes for an example on how you can pass command line args when deploying a pod to Kubernetes. You definitely don't need to bake that into your docker image.

Comment: Yes. I understood the point. Thank you for your response Mr.Amit

Comment: One more doubt I faced that - When I am building Docker image for different tenant. How I can create different images for tenant with different name ? I don't want to hard code anything in Dockerfile. Here I need to create Docker images with different name and need to push to Dockerhub. Is this Docker image building with different name is possible using Pipeline jobs ?

Comment: Here I code repo is same , So Docker image building with different name for tenant need to be do dynamically within Jenkins . Is there any way for doing this?

Comment: If you **must** have different image names. I would suggest running `docker tag` command in loop over your list of tenants.
Do this after you have created your docker image.

Comment: loop over your list means -  Do I need to use shell scripting within Jenkins script text area instead of using Jenkinsfile configuration ?

Comment: Yes, but Jenkins has loop capabilities as well, if you search for it.